# How can I record additional data with pings, such as IP and ISP info?

Tags: networking, internet, isp

I am running after my ISP for last 15 days for unacceptable slow internet speed without any help. I was using SpeedTest.net and testmy.net for testing the speed.

At times SpeedTest fails to load due to configuration failure. On other occasions it used to show slow speed around 300-400 Kbps and at times the speed used to be ok around 1.1-5 Mbps.

But page load speed was very slow and irritating. Now I did a ping test today and it shows packet loss close to 50%. Please see attached images below:

[image]

[image]

Now the ping test does not include my IP address (or any form address from which test was carried out) nor does it contain any detail that the test was conducted on a particular ISP and it also does not show the date and time of the test.

How can I record my IP address, the ISP on which test was carried out, date and time of test in addition to details provided by ping?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Just call them and have them check out your router or something or you'll switch ISPs, this isn't a matter to go to court over. The problem could actually be something you did.

Comment: Regardless of legal advice - you should review your TOS. Most do not contain an SLA and just state "best effort" which means that technically you could be out of service and they don't have to credit your account.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a forum for legal advice so it is doubtful anyone one can help you with what constitutes evidence sufficient for court proceedings.

However, to make a good case to your ISP in asking them to take a look, I'd be sure you do the following:

- make sure you don't have any devices between you and the company provided modem or router.
- use a new cable.
- use a known good PC or laptop.
- boot off of a Linux live CD to eliminate the possibility of OS installation issues.
- note what time of day you did this.
- your cable modem or DSL modem's firmware may record evidence of signal problems - find out what IP your cable modem or DSL modem (for Comcast many of their cable modems are accessible via 192.168.100.1 and DSL 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1) and see if you can access any log pages and save or print them out.
- call your ISP and tell them you want to cancel, then make your case to the person they transfer you to that handles cancellations.

The following commands will provide the information you want:

`date` - outputs your systems date and time, enter that before running `ping`

`ip addr show dev eth0 | grep inet` - will show IP address information for `eth0` which is most likely your wired connection.  It won't be an ISP provided IP address unless there is no router between you and the company provided equipment.  Some DSL modems will still give you an private IP address unless it's in bridge mode.  You'd have to login to the DSL modem to get that information in that case.

`nslookup {IP given to you by your provider}` should be enough to establish that the IP is within the range of your ISP's block though they should know this simply from the public IP given to you by the ISP.

Comment: Please see the updated question.